# Postman gives "socket hang up " error when Dockerized API (flask+cassandra+mysql) is called

Tags: python, docker, flask, postman

I have created a simple flask API to get data from Cassandra and MySQL. When called locally it's working properly but when I dockerize it and call it, the postman is throwing Socket Hangup error.

Github link to source code : [click here](https://github.com/akankshasrivastava-98/flask-cassandra-sql)

docker-compose build output : [docker-compose build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chi9a.jpg)

docker-compose up output : [docker-compose up-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhOac.jpg) [docker-compose up-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr34X.jpg) [docker-compose up-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIacZ.jpg)

Postman output : [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynyoz.jpg)

The above images are the code snippets used. I'm doing docker-compose build and docker-compose up. The images are getting built and the server is running.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the source code and error messages directly in the question, not images and not behind links?  I can't `docker build` that PNG file to try to reproduce the problem, for example.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have put the git link to the source code and put the output images as links. I wasn't able to post it as an image as I'm a new user.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask]. Links can break, or the linked content can change (especially with github links!), making the question unusable for anybody with similar problems. Code on github is probably also too large; we need a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In docker all containers are isolated from your flask application. you need to connect to mysql using container hostname.

```
    connection_pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="pynative_pool",
                                        pool_size=5,
                                        pool_reset_session=True,
                                        host='db',
                                        database='demo',
                                        user='root',
                                        password='your-pass')
```

https://github.com/akankshasrivastava-98/flask-cassandra-sql/blob/master/dbhelper/SQLManager.py#L16-L22

```
    cluster = Cluster(['cassandra-node1'],
                      load_balancing_policy=RoundRobinPolicy(), compression=True, executor_threads=4,
                      default_retry_policy=RetryPolicy.RETRY_NEXT_HOST,
                      reconnection_policy=ExponentialReconnectionPolicy(base_delay=2, max_delay=10))
    _session_domestic = cluster.connect(keyspace=keyspace_name)
```

https://github.com/akankshasrivastava-98/flask-cassandra-sql/blob/master/dbhelper/CassHandler.py#L56-L61

Also, try [dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code) instead of postman.